# My AJAX post variable is not getting to my PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have made an AJAX function, and it actually works, but I can't get the variable with PHP. This is my code:

```
// Validate signup
function validateSignup(){
    // Get values
    var username = document.getElementById("pm_username").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("pm_email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("pm_password").value;
    // Make new object
    var data = {};
    // Make array from object
    data['data'] = [];

    // If values are not empty...
    if(username !== "" || email !== "" || password !== ""){
        data['data'].push(email, username, password);
        // Convert data to JSON string and make new XMLHttpRequest
        var json = JSON.stringify(data['data']), xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Page to open
        xhr.open("POST", "ajax/signup.php", true);
        // Set header to POST
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // Send values
        xhr.send(json);
        console.log(json);

        xhr.onload = function(){
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }

    }else{ // ...or throw new exception
        throw("Some thing was not filled in!");
    }
}
```

It works, but I don't know how I should get the JSON variable in my PHP. This is my PHP code (simple):

```
<?php

$json = $_POST['json'];
echo $json;
echo "Test";

?>
```

It works, because the "Test" echo is being displayed in the console. However, I am getting this back:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: json in <b>G:\usbwebserver\root\pokemonisle\ajax\signup.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
Test
```

That means that the $_POST['JSON'] is not being recognised. I am not using jQuery because I want to learn how XMLHttpRequests work.

Comment: Debugging tip: What does `var_dump($_POST)` say?

Comment: You post array keys that have `email`, `username`, `password` not `json`. Try `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: $_POST says array(0)...

And should I not do $_POST['json'] since I post a JSON string?

Answer (score 0):

Your `POST` array doesn't contain a field named json.

Try the following:

```
<?php 
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

to check which fields you are getting.

To prevent the error you could try:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['json']))
{
    $json = $_POST['json'];
    echo $json;
}
?>
```

and similarly to get other variable you could use:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    echo $username;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not send a post data named 'json', so you can't get it on server side.

Try to stringify your data object like

```
var json = "json="+JSON.stringify(data['data']);
```

and get it as

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
```

You can check out this link.
[Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 0):

> A string is generated of the array when you
> "JSON.stringify(data['data'])" it.
>
> For example the output of this

```
var name ="abc";
var surname ="xyz";
var data ={};
data['data']=[];
data['data'].push(name, surname);
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(json);
```

shall be

> {"data":["abc","xyz"]}

The $_POST['json'] should give you what .???

The $_POST['name'] (in a form for example) gives you the value of the field username.